# Href button in bootbox

Tags: javascript, button, href, bootbox

I have a button with an onclick bootbox, inside the bootbox I wanna have some buttons that redirects to other websites. How do I manage this.

I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: button key btn1 is not allowed (options are ok)

What did I mess up ?

```js
        let infoButton=$('<button/>', 
        {
            'class': 'btn btn-info',
            'data-toggle':'modal',
            'data-target':'#infoModal'
         }).html('<i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>').on("click", function() 
         {
            bootbox.alert(
            {
                    title: "title",
                    message: "text",
                    buttons: 
                {
                    btn1: 
                    {
                        label: "Button 1",
                        callback: function() 
                        {
                            window.open.href("http://www3schools.com");
                        }
                    },
                    btn2: 
                    {
                        label: "Button 2",
                        callback: function() 
                        {
                            window.open.href("http://www3schools.com");
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
         });
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: `bootbox.alert` doesn't contain a button called `btn1`. From what it looks like you're trying to do, you want `bootbox.dialog`.